# Unable to publish .NET Core app (unsupported runtime)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, dotnet-cli

I'm building an API using .net core, and I've just run into this issue during publishing:

```
The project being published does not support the runtime 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-20221'
```

I saw [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2627) as well as [this one](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/76) and I am no closer to a solution. Here is my **updated** `project.json` file:

```
  {
  "compilationOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "OpenIddict.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.EF": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ComponentModel": { "type": "build" }
      }
    },

    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-rc2-*"
        }
      },

      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
      "imports": "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],

  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I read somewhere that it could be due to the organisation of my dependencies?

**UPDATE**

This is the error I get when using `dotnet restore`:

```
Errors in c:\Users\Dude\Documents\my-api-v1\src\MyApi\obj\060296a3-1ddd-4410-9e77-9510cd667f39\bin\project.json
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.0.0-rc2-20832 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.0.0-rc2-20832 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x64).
Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x64).
```

Comment: What's the exact command you're using to publish your project?

Comment: no command, I'm currently using the vs 2015 publish tool, I haven't yet switched to any CI for this. Should I post my publish profile settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're referencing ASP.NET Core RC2 packages that are incompatible with the VS RC1 tooling, as they both rely on totally different stacks (DNX vs .NET CLI).

Instead, you should consider using `dotnet publish`.

I'd recommend updating your `project.json` file to remove the obsolete `commands` section and to include the missing `tools`/`scripts`:

```
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "imports": "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
  }
},

"scripts": {
  "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
}
```

`netstandardapp1.5` should also be replaced by the new `netcoreapp1.0` TFM and the following dependency should be added under `netcoreapp1.0/dependencies`:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "type": "platform", "version": "1.0.0-rc2-*" }
```

You can take a look at https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/project.json for a working example.

Comment: Thanks, am now getting that `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.FileFormatException: unknown keyword platform` error that you discussed [over here](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/88). Any thoughts?

Comment: It's expected. Stop using DNX/VS and ignore it and it should work with .NET CLI.

Comment: heh, okay. I'm using the CLI now, getting a `Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x64)` error. So frustrating...

Comment: Are you using `dnxcore50`? You should use `netcoreapp1.0` instead.

Comment: Only under `imports` do I have dnxcore50, as in the example.

Comment: It would help if you posted your updated `project.json`.

Comment: It looks fine. Could you post the entire error message you're seeing? Also, are you using `dnu restore` or `dotnet restore`?

Comment: Which CLI version are you using? Please post what dotnet --info says.

Comment: 1.0.0-beta-001598. I'm going to update this and try again

Comment: It's indeed way too old. Make sure to uninstall the old bits before installing the newest version.

Comment: `dotnet restore` worked like a charm now :) running into some new publish problems but that's only because I have never published to a remote server from the CLI before, going to go learn more about that.